# Prevent usage of default constructor

Tags: c#

Is there a way to prevent the usage of the default constructor?

All I can think of is throwing an exception, but I would like something that causes a compile time error.

Comment: You may run into trouble if you do this: In .NET a default parameterless constructor is necessary for a number of things (binding/serialization/etc.). Consider having defaults for whatever values you need to set via constructor params. This may not matter in your case, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: a hack: Obsolete attribute

Answer (score 130, accepted):

- If everything in the class is static, consider making it a static class. That way, you won't get a constructor at all.
- If you want a parameterless constructor but you don't want it to be public, declare it explicitly and make it private (or internal etc)
- If you don't want a parameterless constructor but *do* want constructors with parameters, then just declare the parameterized constructor - the default constructor won't be generated for you

I *think* that should cover all bases...

Comment: You said pretty much exactly what I was just typing :)

Comment: I wish I knew about static classes long ago.

Comment: unless, it is a struct and not a class. If this is the case, the default ctor is generated (a good thing so all props are initialized) but callable (unfortunately) - i.e. I want to force the user to use the ctor with params.

Comment: @DaveBlack: Then you'd have problems with arrays, fields etc. It's hard to get round the problem of structs with default values.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea, but I set backing fields as nullable and return their value in properties. So if the default ctor is accidently used, there will be exception later when those properties are called.

Comment: Well i seem to be getting the default constructor as an option when i have defined a constructor with parameters...

Comment: @WDUK: You won't if you're declaring a *class*. You will if you're declaring a *struct*.

Answer (score 42):

Make it private.

So,

```
class SomeClass
{
    private SomeClass()
    {
    }

    public SomeClass(int SomeParam)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you need it within the type (or nested types) you can remove it entirely here - it will only be generated if no constructors are explicitly declared.

Comment: @Jon I'm usually a belt and suspenders kind of guy so I'd normally do it this way anyway; that way what I'm trying to do is clear to anyone looking at it. Good to know that it's handled automatically by the compiler, though, if I forget.

Comment: I would achieve that by adding a comment on the parameterful constructor: "If you remove this constructor, please make sure there's no public default constructor" or something along those lines. Currently this code is basically giving you permission to create an instance without any parameters within the class. It will also cause problems if there are any readonly variables, as you'd have to assign them values...

Comment: @Jon As always, the devil's in the details (I hadn't thought about the ability to create a parameterless instance _inside_ this class). Thanks very much for the tips.

Answer (score 10):

You can just make it private:

```
private MyClass()
{
}
```

Alternatively (if you didn't know already) if you just declare a constructor with parameters, the default one isn't added by the compiler, e.g.

```
private MyClass(string myParameter)
{
    //Can't call new MyClass() anymore
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One thing to mention that others have not. The default constructor should still be able to set up the default implementation bits, to avoid reuse. This is not a problem if it is private, as you can still chain down to a private constructor. You just make it unavailable to outside sources.

```
private MyClass()
{
}

public MyClass(string something) : this()
{
}
```

That solves the problem. Note, however, that protected may actually be a preferred implementation if the class is not sealed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit(!) late to the party. But I found this question when looking for something similar.

Many ORM and serialization frameworks require access to a public a default constructor when creating new objects. In those cases you can cheat a bit by tagging the default constructor with the `Obsolete` attribute like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }

    [System.Obsolete("This not for manual use", true)]
    public MyClass()
    {
        PropA = null!; // We assume that this is always set by a serializer/ORM.
    }

    public MyClass(string propA)
    {
        PropA = propA;
    }
}
```

This will result in a compiler error if you do `new MyClass()`. But it will still work fine with reflection-based frameworks such as serializers and OR-mappers.

Do note that this is **not** the intended use of `Obsolete`! If you for example call the constructor from something that is also marked `Obsolete` you won't get an error, not even a warning.

If you just want to force users to initialize properties, there is a `required`-modifier keyword in C#11 which does it much better. But then you need at least .NET 7.

Comment: that's super useful, thanks. Worked for my case when `System.Text.Json` requires a public empty constructor, but I want to use a different parameterized constructors to guide object creation.