# How to disable parameterless constructor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

```
abstract class CAbstract
{
   private string mParam1;
   public CAbstract(string param1)
   {
      mParam1 = param1;
   }
}

class CBase : CAbstract
{
}
```

For the class CBase, it should be initialized by providing the parameter, so how to disable the parameterless constructor for CBase class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent usage of default constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875581/prevent-usage-of-default-constructor)

Comment: @Sven Maybe this class represents the letter "C" in some application dealing with language processing :D

Comment: a hack: Obsolete attribute

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you define a parameterized constructor in `CBase`, there *is no default constructor*. You do not need to do anything special.

If your intention is for all derived classes of `CAbstract` to implement a parameterized constructor, that is not something you can (cleanly) accomplish. The derived types have freedom to provide their own members, including constructor overloads.

The only thing *required* of them is that if `CAbstract` only exposes a parameterized constructor, the constructors of derived types must invoke it directly.

```
class CDerived : CAbstract
{
     public CDerived() : base("some default argument") { }
     public CDerived(string arg) : base(arg) { }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the extra bit on constraining derived classes. This is why writing good OOP libraries is hard.

Comment: OP states that default constructor is not needed. Why do you show default constructor in your code?

Comment: @Alex, the question is ambiguous, at least to me, hence my second and third paragraphs and the accompanying code snippet. I cannot absolutely tell what he wants, but my *feeling* is that what he wants is something the language does not provide.

Answer (score 13):

To disable default constructor you need to provide non-default constructor.

The code that you pasted is not compilable. To make it compilable you could do something like this:

```
class CBase : CAbstract
{
    public CBase(string param1)
        : base(param1)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think I achieved that goal with this code:

```
//only for forbiding the calls of constructors without parameters on derived classes
public class UnconstructableWithoutArguments
{
    private UnconstructableWithoutArguments()
    {
    }

    public UnconstructableWithoutArguments(params object[] list)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not prevent children from providing parameter-less constructors, it only forces children to invoke the base parameterized constructor explicitly.

Comment: also `params object[] list` can be empty