# Is it possible to set up a required property in a ASP.Net attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I did some quick Googling and didn't come up with any way to do this, so I apologize if this question is a duplicate.

I have a class like:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Authorization
{
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttibute
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress != Address)
                context.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);

            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I add this attribute to other classes in my project, it can be defined two ways. The first way is basically like calling the default constructor for the attribute; no data is passed in. The second way allows `Address` to be specified.

I have a feeling that I can't remove the first option, because it's probably specified somehow through the parent class of the one I created. But is it possible to only have the second option? This would be ideal.

Comment: Create a constructor which takes the `address` as argument.

Comment: Looks like that works. If you write that up as an answer I'll accept it as such. Also, if you know of any relevant sources of information about Asp.Net attributes, I'd appreciate hearing of them. Thanks.

Comment: It is a duplicate, but it would be nice to see a 5.0++ implementation...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10794405/2496266

Comment: @ChaimEliyah what do you mean by 5.0++ implementation?

Comment: Sorry, C# 5.0 or C# 6.0. The answer I linked to has a C# 2.0(?) implementation. It uses auto-properties with backing fields. Seems unnecessary, now.

Comment: To disable the default constructor, you can declare it as private (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875581/prevent-usage-of-default-constructor).

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use a constructor to set the Attribute property (or field), so something like this:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttibute
{
    private readonly string _attribute;

    public AuthorizeAttribute(string attribute)
    {
        _attribute = attribute;
    }
}
```